# How to solve Heap Space Error in Talend Enterprise Big Data

Tags: memory-management, talend

I am using the tFileInputJson and tMongoDBOutput components to store JSON data into a MongoDB Database.

When trying this with a small amount of data (nearly 100k JSON objects), the data can be stored into database with out any problems.

Now my requirement is to store nearly 300k JSON objects into the database and my JSON objects look like:

```
{
  "LocationId": "253b95ec-c29a-430a-a0c3-614ffb059628",
  "Sdid": "00DlBlqHulDp/43W3eyMUg",
  "StartTime": "2014-03-18 22:22:56.32",
  "EndTime": "2014-03-18 22:22:56.32",
  "RegionId": "10d4bb4c-69dc-4522-801a-b588050099e4",
  "DeviceCategories": [
    "ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff",
    "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
  ],
  "CheckedIn": false
}
```

While I am performing this operation I am getting the following Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
[statistics] disconnected
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2367)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:130)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:114)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:415)
at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:237)
at org.json.simple.JSONArray.toJSONString(Unknown Source)
at org.json.simple.JSONArray.toJSONString(Unknown Source)
at org.json.simple.JSONArray.toString(Unknown Source)
at samplebigdata.retail_store2_0_1.Retail_Store2.tFileInputJSON_1Process(Retail_Store2.java:1773)
at samplebigdata.retail_store2_0_1.Retail_Store2.runJobInTOS(Retail_Store2.java:2469)
at samplebigdata.retail_store2_0_1.Retail_Store2.main(Retail_Store2.java:2328)
Job Retail_Store2 ended at 15:14 10/11/2014. [exit code=1]
```

My current job looks like:

[image: Job layout]

How can I store so much data into the database in a single job?

Comment: Can you post a link to a screenshot of your job setup? Someone here will edit it inline with the rest of your post.

Comment: Please find this link https://plus.google.com/u/0/115961411938996992246/posts/V8hsGKLNyt9?pid=6080308116730921266&oid=115961411938996992246

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you're printing the JSON object to the console (with your tLogRow). This requires all of the JSON objects to be held in memory before finally being dumped all at once to the console once the "flow" is completed.

If you remove the tLogRow components then (in a job as simple as this) Talend should only hold whatever the batch size is for your tMongoDbOutput component in memory and keep pushing batches into the MongoDB.

As an example, here's a screenshot of me successfully loading 100000000 rows of randomly generated data into a MySQL database:

[image: Example job loading 2.5 gb of data into MySQL using less than 1 gb of memory]

The data set represents about 2.5 gb on disk when as a CSV but was comfortably handled in memory with a max heap space of 1 gb as each insert is 100 rows so the job only really needs to keep 100 rows of the CSV (plus any associated metadata and any Talend overheads) in memory at any one point.

[image: tMySqlOutput insert settings]

In reality, it will probably keep significantly more than that in memory and simply garbage collect the rows that have been inserted into the database when the max memory is close to being reached.

If you have an absolute requirement for logging the JSON records that are being successfully put into the database then you might try outputting into a file instead and stream the output.

As long as you aren't getting too many invalid JSON objects in your tFileInputJson then you can probably keep the reject linked tLogRow as it will only receive the rejected/invalid JSON objects and so shouldn't run out of memory. As you are restricted to small amounts of memory due to being on a 32 bit system you might need to be wary that if the amount of invalid JSON objects grows you will quickly exceed your memory space.

If you simply want to load a large amount of JSON objects to a MongoDB database then you will probably be best off using the [tMongoDBBulkLoad](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendComponentsReferenceGuide54EN/tMongoDBBulkLoad) component. This takes a flat file (either .csv .tsv or .json) and loads this directly into a MongoDB database. The documentation I just linked to shows all the relevant options but you might be particularly interested by the `--jsonArray` additional argument that can be passed to the database. There is also a basic example in how to use the component.

This would mean you couldn't do any processing mid way through the load and you are having to use a preprepared json/csv file to load the data but if you just want a quick way to load data into the database using Talend then this should cover it.

If you needed to process chunks of the file at a time then you might want to look at a much more complicated job with a loop where you load *n* records from your input, process them and then restart the processing part of the loop but selecting *n* records with a header of *n* records and then repeat with a header of *2n* records and so on...

[Garpmitzn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26842167/2291321) pretty much covers how to change JVM settings to increase memory space but for something as simple as this you just want to reduce the amount you're keeping in memory for no good reason.

As an aside, if you're paying out for an Enterprise licence of Talend then you should probably be able to get yourself a 64 bit box with 16 gb of RAM easily enough and that will drastically help with your development. I'd at least hope that your production job execution server has a bunch of memory.

Comment: I tried by removing the tLogRow components but again i got the same  exception please find the link https://plus.google.com/u/0/115961411938996992246/posts/YnHg51QQn6g?pid=6080391455311201970&oid=115961411938996992246

Comment: What's that subjob below the main one? Can you show me the whole job please?

Comment: The subjob will be in deactivate state,only those 2 components are in active state

Comment: Actually am new to this talend ,so i searched in net and done this job with my some knowledge,is there any better way to store data into database, please let me know

Comment: I don't have the Big Data version of Talend so can't see what options are available to the MongoDB output component. Could you post a screenshot of how you have configured your output component (similar to my example screenshot of the tMySqlOutput) but include all the options in the basic settings tab and another screenshot of the advanced settings tab.

Comment: At first i have taken tFileInputJson and then cliclk on edit schema and enter the details of json object.plese find attached screen shot https://plus.google.com/u/0/115961411938996992246/posts/XLZ1n9LKJWr?pid=6080421410496686754&oid=115961411938996992246

Comment: and then taken tMongoDbOutput and configure like https://plus.google.com/u/0/115961411938996992246/posts/XLZ1n9LKJWr?pid=6080421407880167970&oid=115961411938996992246 and https://plus.google.com/u/0/115961411938996992246/posts/XLZ1n9LKJWr?pid=6080421406248718418&oid=115961411938996992246 ,i didnt configure anything on advanced Setting tab and that tab look like https://plus.google.com/u/0/115961411938996992246/posts/XLZ1n9LKJWr?pid=6080422994370472210&oid=115961411938996992246, please let me know any further details

Comment: You might be best using the bulk load component in this case. I'm not sure why Talend isn't streaming the input to MongoDB or giving any options to do so so that it can garbage collect the sent data but the bulk load component should do this. Alternatively, you will have to set this up in a loop as detailed in my recent edit.

Comment: But in reality you should seriously look at getting yourself a lot more memory and a 64 bit machine for development if you are using an Enterprise platform version of Talend. It doesn't solve it completely but will alleviate a lot of pointless issues.

Comment: I tried and tried by using tMongoDBBulkLoad but i didn't get the proper output please look at screenshots https://plus.google.com/u/0/115961411938996992246/posts/TXBTGFuNPfd?pid=6080781906644009858&oid=115961411938996992246  and plese let me know if am anything doing wrong here.

Comment: What does your abc.json file look like? Did you add --jsonArray as an additional argument? We're quickly getting to the point where no one on StackOverflow is going to be able to help you because this format isn't suited for these back and forth discussions. Your best bet is going to be to potentially raise another question about using tMongoDBBulkLoad or to just throw a lot more memory at your development box.

Answer (score 0):

i feel you are reading into memory of talend. you have to play with java JVM parameters like Xms and XmX - you can increase Xmx to say bigger size then what its currently set for you say if its set to Xmx2048 then increase it to Xmx4096 or otherwise..

these parameters are available in .bat/.sh file of exported job or in talend studio you can find them under Run Job tab Advance settings JVM Settings...

but its advisable, to design the job in such a way that you dont load too much in memory..

Comment: if am adding Xmx4096 then am getting following error  Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4096M
The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.

Comment: Are you using Talend 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: I am using 32bit and is there any variations between 32 and 64 bit

Comment: 32 bit systems are limited to 4 gb of RAM, some of which is required by the OS (and anything else you happen to be running). So you can't give 4 gb of RAM to the Java heap if you only have a max of 4 gb.